# Short-circuiting a stream

Tags: c++, c++11, conditional-statements, iostream

The application has a logging system, that allows to enable or disable logging features of its modules at runtime. The log commands accept streams on input (being a safe alternative to "sprintf"; there's hardly any more annoying situation than if your debugging system is the cause of crash.

The problem is, that if I perform stuff like:

```
 logger.Trace << "Requests pending:" << buffer.findRequests();
```

and `findRequests()` is of high computational complexity, even if disabling Trace log level for the module, the search will be performed (while assembling the stream) before it's rejected inside the Trace `operator<<` method.

The obvious alternative would be to litter the code with:

```
 if(logger.Trace.Enabled()) logger.Trace << ...
```

It's not pretty and it's not comfortable. I could replace it with a macro using `if`, or one that uses `&&` short-circuiting, being somewhat nicer (can be used as RValue, which following Stream philosophy returns bool false on disabled stream):

```
  #define TRACE    if(logger.Trace.Enabled()) logger.Trace

  #define TRACE    dummyLogVar = logger.Trace.Enabled() && logger.Trace
```

Neither is particularly pretty or safe. A co-worker suggested closures:

```
  logger.Trace([&](f){f << "Requests pending:" << buffer.findRequests();});
```

The `.Trace` would evaluate the closure only if that level is enabled. Logically, that's nice, but syntactically absolutely horrific. Typing that mess: `logger.Trace([&](f){f <<` ... `;});` hundreds of times?

Is there any more neat, safe and comfortable way of preventing evaluation of a stream?

Comment: I think closures are about the only way.  I had to solve this same problem prior to the introduction of closures, and I wound up falling back on macros and C-style function calls.

Comment: _"Logically, that's nice, but syntactically absolutely horrific."_ Hehe welcome to C++

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Be happy I didn't use `<:&:>` for the closure. Stumbled upon that one yesterday, baffled me for a good while. In reality `<:` is a digraph for `[`. Who in this day and age still uses digraphs, and why? And why in the world did C++11 extend the set of digraphs and trigraphs?! Did someone misunderstand `embedded programming` and uses Android phone with touchscreen keyboard to write applications for PC?

Comment: @SF.: _"why in the world did C++11 extend the set of digraphs and trigraphs"_ It didn't

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: oh, wait, it didn't add any new ones. It just *modified the interpretation* of one. *When the parser meets the character sequence <:: and the subsequent character is neither : nor >, the < is treated as a preprocessing token by itself and not as the first character of the alternative token*.

Comment: @SF. Didn't even know that. Presumably that was C99's fault though?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: `<::std::...` causing too many headaches I guess.

Comment: @SF.: Hah good point

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Macros can indeed be used, but you need function-like macros that takes the output as an argument, and you need to make sure it's a single statement.

The second part, making sure the macro body is a single statement, is easy and usually done by using `do { ... } while (false)`.

Using an argument to the macro is not hard either, as long as there's no commas in the argument. The comma-limitation is including using function calls in the macro-argument with its own arguments, the preprocessor is pretty stupid any uses *any* comma in the macro argument as a separator of arguments for the macro.

In its simplest form, without bothering with the comma-limitation, the macro could then look something like

```
#define TRACE(output)                   \
    do                                  \
    {                                   \
        if (logger.Trace.Enabled())     \
        {                               \
            logger.Trace << output;     \
        }                               \
     } while (false)
```

<sub>Note that there is no semicilon after the `while (false)`.</sub>

You then use it like

```
TRACE("Requests pending:" << buffer.findRequests());
```

The `do { ... } while (false)` part will most likely be optimized away by the compiler, leaving you with a simple `if` check. If `logger.Trace.Enabled()` returns `false` then nothing should happen besides that check.

If you have a compiler capable of C++11 or later it should have support for [variadic macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro) which should help you overcome the limitation about commas in the argument to the macro.

Using variadic macros, the macro instead would look like this:

```
#define TRACE(...)                       \
    do                                   \
    {                                    \
        if (logger.Trace.Enabled())      \
        {                                \
            logger.Trace << __VA_ARGS__; \
        }                                \
     } while (false)
```

Comment: You can solve this problem without variadic macros. Define `TRACE` as a macro that takes no arguments, where `TRACE` is replaced with a call to a function that returns a function pointer to a function that takes variable arguments.  Have that function call return one of two functions depending on the logging being enabled.  If the logging is enabled, return a function that actually logs the data.  If the logging isn't enabled, return a function that simply returns without doing anything:  `void ( *traceFunc )( const char *fmt, ... );` then `#define TRACE traceFunc()`. Doesn't do C++ IO, though

Comment: @AndrewHenle but then, even if logging is disabled, log message is still computed and then discarded, which OP wants to avoid.

Comment: @el.pescado  True.  I don't think it's possible to fully solve that aspect of the problem without using variadic macros.  It would certainly be interesting to see such a solution.  A pure C++ IO solution would be interesting, as well - by that I mean one that doesn't require C-style parenthesis at all - it simply uses the `<<` operator.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I know of one that doesn't use (). It just uses {}. `try { logger.Trace << "whatever"; } catch(LoglevelDisabledException ex){}`. I think you see why I didn't suggest that one ;)

Answer (score 0):

I worked on that problem. Finnaly, I created a class `Log` with this interface and associated macros :

```
class Log
{
  public:
    static bool trace_is_active();
    static bool debug_is_active();
    static bool info_is_active();
    static bool warning_is_active();
    static bool error_is_active();
    static void write_as_trace(const std::string& msg);
    static void write_as_debug(const std::string& msg);
    static void write_as_info(const std::string& msg);
    static void write_as_warning(const std::string& msg);
    static void write_as_error(const std::string& msg);
};

#define LOG_TRACE(X) {if(Log::trace_is_active()){std::ostringstream o__;o__<<X;Log::write_as_trace(o__.str());}}
#define LOG_DEBUG(X) {if(Log::debug_is_active()){std::ostringstream o__;o__<<X;Log::write_as_debug(o__.str());}}
#define LOG_INFO(X) {if(Log::info_is_active()){std::ostringstream o__;o__<<X;Log::write_as_info(o__.str());}}
#define LOG_WARNING(X) {if(Log::warning_is_active()){std::ostringstream o__;o__<<X;Log::write_as_warning(o__.str());}}
#define LOG_ERROR(X) {if(Log::error_is_active()){std::ostringstream o__;o__<<X;Log::write_as_error(o__.str());}}
```

Then usage is very easy and clear :

```
//...
LOG_WARNING("The variable x = " << x << " is out of range");
//...
LOG_DEBUG("The inverse of the matrix is inv(m) = " << std::endl << inv(m) << std::endl);
```

**EDIT :** I note that the solution with `do{...}while(false)` is better because my solution followed by `;` is two instructions and can't be used in loops or condition without writing it between `{` and `}`. 
Now I can improve my code. :-)